# Must if addclass by addremove

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add / remove a class to an element when the URL?

I want to do with if

Example

> if url
>
> { addclass('active'); //true
>
> } else {
>
> removeclass('active'); //false
>
> }

```js
var url = window.location.href; 

$('.info-project').find('a').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-project">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When the URL is... what?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , just example code

Comment: I mean you didn't really finish the sentence. Do you want to highlight the link in your menu that corresponds to currently loaded document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : put your code inside `$(function(){})` so that DOM will be loaded. Put if else condition as shown below

```js
$(function(){
var url = window.location.href; 

$('.info-project').find('a').each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('href') == url){
      $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-project">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you have `#` in sample code posted for href value, is this the case for real code? If yes, then it will not match the url value. Try to debug the code and find out what is the actual value of url and href.